# IOS XR: A command like "show running-config all"

Tags: configuration-managment

On an IOS router, the "show running-config all" command displays commands that are included by default or have been entered with default parameters.

What is the equivalent in IOS XR?

Or is there a work-around in IOS XR?

Comment: Probably asked at wrong StackExchange site. But which one is more suitable?

Comment: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ would be the correct SE site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

See [this bug case](https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCds49706/?rfs=iqvred) (which is actually an enhancement request). If you login to your CCO account it will show you:

> Status: Terminated, Known Fixed Releases: No release planned to fix
>   this bug